# POST запрос к API Ozon

Tags: python, api, requests

Я пытаюсь сделать запрос по Api Ozon, чтобы добавить товар в карзину. Url запроса нашел во вкладке Сеть в браузере

[image: URL запроса]

Вот код как я это делаю

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.ozon.ru/api/composer-api.bx/_action/addToCart'

data = {'id': '428492725', 'quantity' : '1'}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}

s = requests.Session()

response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Однако как бы я не пытался всегда приходит ответ "Код 400".
Данные, которые я передаю вот:
[image: Данные]

Я так понял что ошибка 400 означает "Неверный формат данных"
Возможно ли сделать post запрос и добавить товар в карзину?

Comment: Может ozon понимает что вы не браузер?

Comment: @СергейШашко Я пробовал ставить User-agent, но также все тчетно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
json_data = [
        {
            'id': 420394568,
            'quantity': 1,
        },
    ]

response = requests.post('https://www.ozon.ru/api/composer-api.bx/_action/addToCart', json=json_data)
print(response)
    
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: Кто бы ты ни был Герой, но ты мой спаситель! А как вы поняли что запрос должен быть в таком формате?

Comment: У одного ютубера посмотрел одну классную фишку, чтоб самому не выписывать куки, хендлеры и д.т. в готывый код пайтон